# Microsoft Graph Login - Personal accounts trigger "User account does not exist in tenant"

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

My web app uses the Microsoft Graph API to sign in users and access their calendars. I'm currently experiencing an issue upon trying to sign up with a Live/Hotmail account. After that Live/Hotmail account is selected, Microsoft sends the user to a page with this message:

> User account 'xxxxx@yyyy.com' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'MY_TENANT_NAME' and cannot access the application 'MY_APP_ID'(MY_APP_NAME) in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.

My web app is registered with Microsoft Azure as "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)". As this is a personal account I'm trying to sign up with, I expected it to just let me sign up. I've entered a Redirect URI & a Logout URL, I've left "Access tokens" & "ID tokens" unchecked, "Live SDK support" is "Yes", and "Default client type" is "No".

I'm using the Python MSAL to send the user to MS:

```
def _build_msal_app(cache=None):
    return msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
        MY_CLIENT_ID, authority=MY_AUTHORITY,
        client_credential=MY_CLIENT_SECRET, token_cache=cache)

# Send user to MS Login
session["state"] = str(uuid.uuid4())
auth_url = _build_msal_app().get_authorization_request_url(
            MY_SCOPES,
            state=session["state"],
            redirect_uri=MY_REDIRECT_URI)

return flask.redirect(auth_url)
```

I suspected my application registration was somehow corrupt, so I registered a 2nd application and updated the ID's in my code, but that didn't fix it. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What's the endpoint you're being sent to for authorization? It should be `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common` endpoint.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like your authority is set to your single-tenant endpoint.

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS You're absolutely right, that fixed it! Microsoft's documentation is the worst. Submit that as an answer and I'll accept it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, in order to support both "Personal Microsoft" accounts and "Work/School" accounts, your authorization request must be sent to `common` endpoint i.e. `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common`.

You may find this link helpful for understanding about different endpoints: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols#endpoints.

Comment: Jesus. THANK you! I had spent literally hours wondering why I couldnt refresh the token.